# SlideUp/SlideDown в списке ul

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. У меня есть список:

```js
$('.top').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('open-menu')) {
    $(this).removeClass('open-menu');
    $(this).parent().children('.pod-menu').slideUp('slow');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('open-menu');
    $(this).parent().children('.pod-menu').slideDown('slow');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>Одежда для малышей</span>
    <div class='pod-menu'>
      <a>Шапки</a>
      <a>Обувь</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>Одежда для женщин</span>
    <div class='pod-menu'>
      <a>Шапки</a>
      <a>Обувь</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>Одежда для мужчин</span>
    <div class='pod-menu'>
      <a>Шапки</a>
      <a>Обувь</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

По клику на `top`, у меня к `pod-menu`добавляется `dislpay: block`, но если нажать на другую категорию, то у предыдущей категории подменю не скрывается. Подскажите как можно сделать так, чтобы по клику на одну категорию подменю раскрывалось только у нее, а у остальных скрывалось?

Answer (score 0):

Ищем все подменю, кроме текущего, и закрываем. Я не стал выделять одинаковые фрагменты кода в переменные, чтоб было понятней, но вам следует это сделать

```js
$('.pod-menu').slideUp()
// $('.pod-menu').not($(this)).slideDown()

$('.top').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open-menu')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open-menu');
            $(this).parent().children('.pod-menu').slideUp('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('open-menu');
            $('.pod-menu').not($(this).parent().children('.pod-menu')).slideUp()
            $(this).parent().children('.pod-menu').slideDown('slow');

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
  <span class='top'>Одежда для малышей</span>
     <div class='pod-menu'>
        <a>Шапки</a>
        <a>Обувь</a>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span class='top'>Одежда для женщин</span>
   <div class='pod-menu'>
      <a>Шапки</a>
      <a>Обувь</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>Одежда для мужчин</span>
    <div class='pod-menu'>
      <a>Шапки</a>
      <a>Обувь</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```